# Ugly LINQ statement, a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ statement which is adding up the values of multiple columns, each beginning with 'HH' although there are other columns available:

```
//TODO Clean up this mess
var query1 = (from e in Data
                where e.SD == date
                select e).Select(x =>   x.HH01 + x.HH16 + x.HH17 + x.HH18 + x.HH19 + x.HH20 + x.HH21 + x.HH22 + x.HH23 +
                                        x.HH24 + x.HH25 + x.HH26 + x.HH27 + x.HH28 + x.HH29 + x.HH30 + x.HH31 + x.HH32 + 
                                        x.HH33 + x.HH34 + x.HH35 + x.HH36 + x.HH37 + x.HH38 + x.HH39 + x.HH40 + x.HH41 +
                                        x.HH42 + x.HH43 + x.HH44 +x.HH45 + x.HH46 + x.HH47 + x.HH48 + x.HH49.GetValueOrDefault()+
                                        x.HH50.GetValueOrDefault());

return query1.FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there any way to tidy this up?  I have to do lots of variations of this (in different methods) so it would clear out a lot of 'fluff' if it could be.

Also I'd like to call `.GetValueOrDefault()` on each column, but currently I've taken this out due to the mess except for the last two columns.

Suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Are the values you have to add always the same? So always HH01, HH16, HH17, ... ?

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: @WouterdeKort: I'm guessing not, seeing as he has to do variations...

Comment: @FarligOpptreden I meant if it is X = HH01 + HH02, Y = HH03 + HH01. Then you could move X and Y to be properties on e

Comment: The HH etc are all different columns, of which I have to do variations (otherwise they're just unrelated numbers).  I'm using LINQ to Entities with an Oracle backend.

Comment: Under what situations do these column sets change?  Is it when the database schema changes, or at runtime?  If it's the former then you may be able to generate the code.  If it's the latter then is there any way to get the list of column names?

Comment: The column sets change based on the operation required.  So if I can method1 it'll only calculate using HH1 and HH2 but another method may use other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use Reflections for this:

```
double GetHHSum<T>(T x) where T : class
{
   double result = 0;

   var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
   foreach (var property in properties)
   {
       if (property.Name.StartsWith("HH"))
          sum += Convert.ToSingle(property.GetValue(x)).GetValueOrDefault();
   }

   return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
return (from e in Data
        where e.SD == date
        select e).ToList().Select(x => GetHHSum(x)).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Code is not tested**

Comment: This won't work, because the provider doesn't know how to translate `GetHHSum` to SQL.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Not it will not try to translate it into SQL, but just use Linq helper extension to select right things.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. Please, mark as answer, if it helped. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't ask this question, I just pointed out the problems in your answer ;-)

Comment: Slight enhancement. Change to `typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("HH"))` and then there's no need to check this inside the `for` loop.

Comment: +1 Cosmin. Reflection is around 1000x slower than static code

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong because I don't know your data, but it seems to me that they are not fully normalized (repetitive attributes).
You might consider going to the 3rd form normal - thus create a/some separate table that will contain one value by row - and then to join your 2 tables in your linq query.

The link query will look much much better, and you will later be able to change your HH fields without changing your queries.

Comment: The data has nothing to do with me, I've merely got a database table (which I cannot change or modify in any way) and have to extract the data as it is

Comment: There's nothing in the posted code that shows the data is not normalized

Comment: Cosmin: indeed my answer is based on a lot of assumptions. what led me is the usage of the term "column" in the question. Also, with experience it is easy to recognize this kind of issues and to solve them at the root (the data)

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to refactor the above code to use LINQ method chains and lambdas (personal preference), then extract the select lambda into a separate method. For instance:

```
// Note select e and .Select(x => x..) is redundant. Only need one
var query1 = Data.Where(e => e.SD == date).Select(SumOfHValues);
return query1.FirstOrDefault();

// Note types are unclear in your question so I've put dummy placeholders
private static QueryResultType SumOfHValues(YourInputClassType x)
{
    // Nothing wrong with this syntactically, it will be faster than a 
    // reflection solution
    // 
    // Algorithmic code tends to have this sort of look & feel. 
    // You could make it more readable
    // by commenting exactly what the summation is doing and 
    // with a mathematical notation or link to documentation / web source
    return x.HH01 + x.HH16 + x.HH17 + x.HH18 + 
           x.HH19 + x.HH20 + x.HH21 + x.HH22 + 
           x.HH23 + x.HH24 + x.HH25 + x.HH26 + 
           x.HH27 + x.HH28 + x.HH29 + x.HH30 + 
           x.HH31 + x.HH32 + x.HH33 + x.HH34 + 
           x.HH35 + x.HH36 + x.HH37 + x.HH38 + 
           x.HH39 + x.HH40 + x.HH41 + x.HH42 + 
           x.HH43 + x.HH44 + x.HH45 + x.HH46 + 
           x.HH47 + x.HH48 + 
           x.HH49.GetValueOrDefault() +
           x.HH50.GetValueOrDefault()
}
```

In addition if you wanted to call GetValueOrDefault() on each HHxx property you could wrap this in a further helper function. this really boils down to code preference. Which do you prefer? Seeing .GetValueOrDefault() on the end of each property access or a function around it? e.g.

```
return x.HH01 + x.HH16 + x.HH17 + x.HH18
```

becomes

```
return Get(x.HH01) + Get(x.HH16) + Get(x.HH17) + Get(x.HH18) ... 

private static HClassType Get(HClassType input)
{ 
    return input.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Personally I would just go with ordering my HHxx + HHyy code in columns and calling .GetValueOrDefault() on each one. If it's put in a helper method at least its only written once, even if it is verbose.

Best regards,